# $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a^{-\ln(\ln(n))}$ for every $a>1$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, functions, improper-integrals

I want to determine if this sum is convergent or divergent: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a^{-\ln(\ln(n))}$ for every $a>1$.

Define $f(x)=a^{-\ln(\ln(x))}$ for every $x \ge 2$.

$f$ is decreasing (since $a^{\ln(\ln(x))}$ is increasing), so we can use the Integral test,

But I find it hard to calculate $\int_2^\infty a^{-\ln(\ln(n))}$.

Any hints to solve this integral (hints only please)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Hint :** $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}= o \left(a^{-\ln(\ln(n))}\right)$$ so the series diverges.

Comment: **Hint:** [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) states that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a^{-\ln(\ln(n))}$ converges iff $ \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n a^{-\ln(\ln(2^n))} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n a^{-(\ln(n) + \ln(2))}$ converges, and what can we say about the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n a^{-(\ln(n) + \ln(2))} ?$

Answer (score 1):

By repeated use of L'Hôpital's rule, for any $\ r>0,$

$$\displaystyle\lim_{u\to\infty} \frac{u^r}{e^u} = \displaystyle\lim_{u\to\infty} \frac{ru^{r-1}}{e^u}=\ldots= \displaystyle\lim_{u\to\infty} \frac{r(r-1)\ldots (r-\lfloor r\rfloor)u^{r-\lceil r \rceil}}{e^u} = \frac{0}{+\infty} = 0.\qquad (1)$$

Let $\ x=e^u,\ $ so that $\ \large{\frac{u^r}{e^u}\  = \frac{(\ln x)^r}{x}}.\quad$ We have: $\ u\to\infty\iff x\to\infty.\ $ Therefore:

$$ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\ln x)^r}{x} = 0. $$

So regardless of the choice of $\ r>0,\ x\ $ is eventually greater than $\ (\ln x)^r.\qquad (2)$

$\large{a^{-\ln(\ln(x))} \equiv \frac{1}{\ln(x)^{ln(a)}} }$.

Since $\ a>1,\ \ln(a)>0.$

From $\ (2),\ \exists\ c>2\ $ s.t.

$$(\ln x)^r < x,\quad \therefore\ \frac{1}{(\ln x)^r} > \frac{1}{x}>0\qquad \forall x\geq c\qquad (3)$$

Therefore,

$$ \displaystyle\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(x)^{ln(a)}} dx = \underset{\Large{=\ b\ \in\ \mathbb{R}}}{\underbrace{\displaystyle\int_2^c \frac{1}{\ln(x)^{ln(a)}} dx}} + \displaystyle\int_c^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(x)^{ln(a)}} dx = b + \displaystyle\int_c^\infty\frac{1}{\ln(x)^{ln(a)}} dx \geq b + \displaystyle\int_c^\infty\frac{1}{x} dx = \infty.$$

Comment: Anything wrong or suspicious about my answer?